# How can I restore the shine to a quartz countertop?

Tags: kitchen-counters

My kitchen counter top is made of QUARTZ, and I have a small area that the shine is dull. Can the surface be restored to make the shine uniform as it was?

Answer (score 1):

Do not use sealer on engineered stone, it has to be mechanically re-polished if it's lost its luster due to abrasion. If you're lucky it's just dirty.

> Of course, you cannot apply a sealer to Silestone quartz countertops, so it's just a matter of cleaning it. –[countertopspecialty.com](http://www.countertopspecialty.com/silestone-countertops-polishing-cleaning.html)

---

> Do not use oil-based soaps for this. Dulling of the shine occurs because of residue left behind on the countertop. Oil-based soaps are often used on porous surfaces because they are designed to soak in, not to be completely removed. Standard dish soap is best. [...]
>
> To remove cooking film from the quartz, spray the space with **window cleaner**. [...]
>
> Avoid Using More Polish. Quartz countertops are polished within the manufacturing company, using a sealing surface polish. Further polish added to the top will only create excess buildup which will further the dull look.
>
> –How to Polish a Quartz Countertop to Make it Shine, [doityourself.com](http://www.doityourself.com/stry/how-to-polish-a-quartz-countertop-to-make-it-shine)